# 'float' object is not iterable

Tags: python, sfml

```
for s in objectList:
    s.ratio = 0.99
```

I am trying to iterate over a list of Shape objects in python, and scale them down. However, I am getting the following error:

```
Exception TypeError: "'float' object is not iterable" in
'pysfml.system.to_vector2f' ignored
```

I do not understand what this means in this context. I am not iterating over floats... and something like:

```
for s in objectList:
    print(s)
```

Works as I would expect.

Ideas?

EDIT: `print(type(objectList))` prints `class 'list'`

There are no other errors.

Comment: please post the full traceback

Comment: what is the output of `print type(objectList)` ? It is probably float.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ratio`](http://python-sfml.org/api/graphics.html#sfml.graphics.Transformable.ratio) must be a 2-vector:

```
for s in objectList:
    s.ratio = sfml.system.Vector2(0.99, 0.99)
```

The property’s setter sees that the given value is not a vector, so it tries to convert it to one by iterating it. Obviously, `0.99` cannot be iterated, hence the error.

Tuples, however, can be iterated. Therefore, a 2-tuple works too, and will automatically be converted to a 2-vector by the property’s setter:

```
for s in objectList:
    s.ratio = 0.99, 0.99
```